# Get-Module equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I am developing PowerShell cmdlets in a module using C#.

I need to get module information like name, description, path, etc. In PowerShell I use Get-Module cmdlet and extract information from this. How can I use an equivalent method in c# to get module information?
Does GetModuleCommand() retrieve module information? If yes, how can I use this method to extract module details?

The corresponding Powershell code is:

```
$mod = Get-Module | ? {$_.Name -eq "CmdletSet"}
$versionObject = New-Object PSObject
$versionObject | Add-member "Name" $mod.Name
$versionObject | Add-member "Path" $mod.Path
$versionObject | Add-member "Description" $mod.Description
```

Here $versionObject get the details of the module. How can this be done in C#?

Answer (score 1):

This [MSDN Topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714876%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) shows how to call a cmdlet from within a cmdlet.